# Why are the Year,Month and Day properties of the DateTime Object of type int32 and not of type int16

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I was creating a method that gets me the minimum year from an SQL table hosting some data, and to save space and memory, I created the method with return type of int16. I was surprised to see that the Year, Month and Day properties of the DateTime object are of type int 32, which I think is useless and a is a waste of memory. Is there a reason that Microsoft declared them as int32 and not int16.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728787/does-it-really-matter-to-distinct-between-short-int-long

Comment: @Tim, Thanks. so using int16 instead of int 32 will not have advantages? not will it save memory?

Comment: It will only save some memory when you have very large arrays. Otherwise, don't bother.

Comment: @Henk, Thanks, you are true about this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The internal representation of the .Net DateTime struct is not d/m/y/s but rather a 64bit integer representing the number of ticks since an epoch.

The properties are returned as integers as they are easier to work with and are normally the cheapest data type to process.

Comment: Why "easier to work with" and "cheapest" in what way?

Comment: They are cheaper because using other sizes require special treatment as the given platform will be "fastest" at integer maths on it's native register size.
This is complicated by the way the CLR, compilers and processors actually behave though.

Answer (score 2):

`DateTime` is single 64 bit value irrespective of what type of its properties are. The year, month, day are packed inside that value and take much less space than even `Int16`.

Now there is not much benefit to return anything but `Int32` from the properties as most CPUs are dealing better with native integer sizes (int32/int64) rather than smaller ones - so you may need slower/more complex code generated to some questionable savings.

You can obviously store the resulting values in smaller types if you indeed need to store them in something like "array of days", but it is good idea to measure performance impact - you may find surprising results...